# Java SystemTray icon

Tags: java, icons, tray

There is [a really simple tutorial on implementing a system tray icon](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/).

The problem is, I can see the icon in tray if I run my app from eclipse, but I can't see it if I export and run a runnable jar file. I have other images in my app that work fine form the same folder.

The tray is working (left and right click on it) but doesn't show the image, like you can see in the image (the jar file on top, with eclipse on bottom):

[image: Example of the Missing image]

Why?  Thank you and sorry for my english!

**EDIT**: I finally found the solution the image need to be accessed whit:

```
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(MyClass.class.getResource("/images/asd.png"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you include the image file. You **will have to include the image in the JAR** when you create it, and you will have to access the image in a different manner:

```
try {
    InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("wing16.png");
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
}
catch (IOException e) {}
```

You can just used the `img` variable to set the image in the JAR.

**Update:**

Take all of your class files & images and go to command line:

`jar -cvfm Test.jar Manifest.mft *.class image.png`

Replace `Manifest.mft` with your manifest file name. Replace `image.png` with the image you want to show up (you can include more images if you need to)

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, my image is included in the jar, like i said before i have other images included that worj fine on the jframe. I'm trying your solution, but doesn't seems to work...

Comment: yes sure!!! i have this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the `try/catch`

Comment: sorry your first answer work in eclipse without errors, but again not in jar. Maybe i did first wrong import, i't 4.00 am here. I'll try again tomorrow, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: To get it to work with both "eclipse" and "jar" you need to add the image to the build path. Do it and the solution above will work for both!

Comment: Hi, don't know why, but i have to put the image in the project root folder (i had it in res/images). Now it works with my original code too. Thank you very much to all.

Comment: no, wrong again, it doesn't work with my code. Have again to figure out it.

Comment: Solved!! i add the solution on my first post.